# Always use D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE and D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET?

Tags: directx-11, directx-10

Is there performance side effects or any other side effects from always defining standard  directx buffers with the bind flags D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE and D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET with the exception of more specialised buffers such as index, vertex, constant etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes

Bind Flags will associated the resource with a shader stage or how to access it. The device will not be able to optimize for its use.

Also it can cause an issue when trying to combine with another flag, example: D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE can not be use with D3D11_MAP_WRITE_NO_OVERWRITE

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476085(v=vs.85).aspx

> Remarks
>
> In general, binding flags can be combined using a logical OR (except the constant-buffer flag);>  however, you should use a single flag to allow the device to optimize the resource usage.